# Start at 1 again after null expression in Row_Number()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a question about `Row_Number()` in SQL Server. First, I'm sharing the query and the result below.

```
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordingDurationSeconds_Yeni, ContactCode, CAST(Calldate AS date) 
                       ORDER BY RecordingDurationSeconds_Yeni, Calldate) AS RowT 
FROM
    #tbl1
ORDER BY
    ContactCode, CallDate
```

[image]

By the way, I used the following structure to create the 'RecordingDurationSeconds_Yeni' column;

```
CASE 
    WHEN fcs.RecordingDurationSeconds > 0 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
END AS RecordingDurationSeconds_Yeni
```

What I want to do is as follows:

[image]

So, if the `RecordingDurationSeconds` column is full, I print 1. Then let it continue with 1 instead of 4. Can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is called "gaps and islands".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work. The column rowT is now based on a group column (grp) that increases when RecordingDurationSeconds has content (is not null), resetting the counter.

```sql
SELECT [ContactCode], [CallDate] ,RecordingDurationSeconds,
       (case when RecordingDurationSeconds IS NULL then row_number() over (partition by ContactCode, grp, RecordingDurationSeconds order by ContactCode, CallDate)
             else 1
        end) as rowT
from (select tbl1.*, sum(case when RecordingDurationSeconds IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by ContactCode order by ContactCode, CallDate) as grp
      from tbl1
     ) t
order by ContactCode, CallDate
```

The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/565912/42) used

Comment: There's no point in ordering on the same columns in a partition.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach but rooted in the same concepts:

```
with data as (
    select *, case when RecordingDurationSeconds is not null then 1 end as flag
    from T
), grouped as (
    select *, count(flag) over (partition by ContactCode order by CallDate desc) as grp
    from data
)
select *,
    coalesce(flag, row_number() over (partition by ContactCode, grp order by CallDate)) as rowT
from grouped
order by ContactCode, CallDate;
```

Also:

```
with data as (
    select *, case when lag(RecordingDurationSeconds, 1, 1) over (partition by ContactCode order by CallDate) is not null then 1 end as brk
    from T
), grouped as (
    select *, count(brk) over (partition by ContactCode order by CallDate) as grp
    from data
)
select *, coalesce(sign(RecordingDurationSeconds), row_number() over (partition by ContactCode, grp order by CallDate)) as rowT
from grouped
order by ContactCode, CallDate;
```